# Is there any way to iterate in a range of (1, 10 ^-1, 10 ^-2 ,...,10 ^-11) in Python?

Tags: python

I am using the range function but I cant get the values these 12 values (1,10^-1, 10^-2, ...,10^-11). Does anyone know how can I generate this simple series of numbers. I want to iterate with this numbers.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over `range(12)` then calculate `10 ** (-1 * whatever)` for each one?

Answer (score 3):

Genex:

```
for val in (10 ** -ex for ex in range(12)):
   ...
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may create your custom iterator as:

```
def my_range(num, pow_start, pow_end):
    for i in range(pow_start, pow_end):
        yield num**(-i)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> for i in my_range(10, 0, 12):
...     print i
...
1
0.1
0.01
0.001
0.0001
1e-05
1e-06
1e-07
1e-08
1e-09
1e-10
1e-11
```